# Selected tab is barely distinguishable from other tabs

Tags: google-chrome

I have to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.3 and after that my Chrome browser looks like this:

[image]

As you see, the selected tab is barely distinguishable from other tabs. That causes this, and how to fix that?